# Solution to point customers domains at our SAAS app

Tags: node.js, ssl, dns

I have a SAAS application on node express. The app creates tenant sub-domains for each sign up like mybiz.ourgreatapp.com.

We want to allow the users to point a custom domain at that account/url, ie a domain they have bought.

somedomainibought.com---->mybiz.ourgreatapp.com

We also need that domain to be HTTPS.

Uur domain, and wildcard sub domains are SSL.

So: https://mybiz.ourgreatapp.com: works.

We have tried to solve the problem using https://www.cloudflare.com which works for our sub-domain routes but we can't set it up to use customers domains and point them at those routes.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To create certificaes for different domains

You need to solve 2 problems:

1. that your customers should point their domains to your IP/domain in order to use your service. Solution for it: you can create a dedicated domain like cname.ourgreatapp.com. If customer wants to use his own custom domain - he should point his domain (in 99% cases it will be customer's subdomain) to your CNAME. In 1% cases when customer would like to attach domain - better to provide also public IP for such customers. As not all DNS providers support using CNAME for 1st level domain
2. that you need to issue certificate for the customer. When you issue a certificate, you must prove your rights for this domain (different certificates authorities provide multiple options in order to do it). Luckily when you already have a customer who already pointed to your CNAME - you can use "HTTP validation type" (when you should provide specific text at some URL and CA verifies that secret value is there by doing GET request. For example, free LetsEncrypt certificate provider will verify specific value at the URL customersdomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/)
   This second step I suppose is too heavy to be handled by your node-express application. Better to extract SSL-signing logic to a separate layer, even to a separate micro-service.

In order to automate this process, you can create a service which will request SSL for all your customer's domains (for example by implementing ACME protocol, requesting certificates from LetsEncrypt). And setup proxy server which will proxy requests from all customer's domains, getting data and signing the responses with proper certificates.

Also you can check third party solutions which already do this from the box. For example, Kilo SSL, Cloudflare etc. I didn't try doing it with Cloudflare yet, but just checked that it's easy to do with KiloSSL

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a reverse proxy (using nginx for example). Configure a virtual host with server name somedomainibought.com that does a proxy pass to https://mybiz.ourgreatapp.com/. Configure this virtual host to use ssl and listen on port 443.

Then, the Zone file for the domain somedomainibought.com must be configured with an A record pointing to the IP address of your reverse proxy.